# Proving an inequality of exponential functions using the triangle inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a$ and $b$ be complex numbers whose real parts are negative. Prove the inequality $|e^a−e^b|<|a−b|$ using the triangle inequality.
I'm having trouble completing my proof.

The triangle inequality for the exponential functions states that $|e^z - e^w| \le |e^z| + |e^w| = e^{\operatorname{Re}(z)} + e^{\operatorname{Re}(w)}$ for any complex numbers $z$ and $w$.

Using this inequality, we can write:
\begin{align*}
|e^a - e^b| &= |e^a - e^{\operatorname{Re}(b)}e^{\operatorname{Im}(b)i}| 
&= |e^a| \cdot |1 - e^{\operatorname{Re}(b)-a+\operatorname{Im}(b)i}| 
&\leq |e^a| \cdot (e^{\operatorname{Re}(b)-a} + e^{-\operatorname{Re}(b)+a}) 
&= |e^a| \cdot 2\cosh(\operatorname{Re}(b) - a) 
&\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

I do not see how to apply the triangle inequality. Instead assume that ${\rm Re }\,b\le {\rm Re}\,a<0.$
Then $$|e^a-e^b|=e^{{\rm Re}\,a}|1-e^{b-a}|<|1-e^{b-a}|$$ Set $z=b-a.$ It suffices to show that $|1-e^z|\le |z|.$ We have $z=-x+iy,$ where $x\ge 0.$
Thus
$$|1-e^z|^2=(1-e^{-x}\cos y)^2+e^{-2x}\sin^2y\\
=(1-e^{-x})^2+2e^{-x}(1-\cos y)\\
\le x^2+2(1-\cos y)=x^2+4\sin^2(y/2)\le x^2+y^2=|z|^2$$

Comment: can u please explain the first step after assumption how come $$|e^a-e^b|=e^{{\rm Re}\,a}|1-e^{b-a}|$$ ?

Comment: @Ash_Blanc $e^a-e^b=e^a(1-e^{b-a}),$ $|e^a|=e^{{\rm Re}\,a}$

Comment: can u please explain the last step too i.e., $$(1-e^{-x})^2+2e^{-x}(1-\cos y)\\
\le x^2+2(1-\cos y)\le x^2+y^2=|z|^2$$

Comment: @Ash_Blanc Re-edited